# LINQ Search attributes on different levels

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I would like to search xml file with LINQ technology but have some difficulties.
I would like to find all childs with attribute value and some search condition

My XML (structured data) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<LanguageMenu>
    <Menu language="English" name ="Menu" numOfMenus="1">
        <MainItem ID="e_mnuMain1" name="File" level="0"></MainItem>
        <MainItem ID="e_mnuMain2" name="Edit" level="0"></MainItem>
        <MainItem ID="e_mnuMain3" name="Query" level="0"></MainItem>
        <MainItem ID="e_mnuMain4" name="Traffic" numOfSubItem="4" level="0"> 
            <SECOND name="Vendors" value="FIN3010" level="1" father="3"></SECOND>
            <SECOND name="Buyers" value="FIN3020" level="1" father="3" ></SECOND>
            <SECOND name="General ledger" value="FIN3030" level="1" father="3"></SECOND>
            <SECOND name="Accounts" value="FIN3040" level="1" father="3">
                <THIRD name="Home Accounts" value="FIN3010" level="2" father="5" grantfather="3"/>
                <THIRD name="Foreign accounts" value="FIN3050" level="2" father="5" grantfather="3"/>
            </SECOND>
        </MainItem>
    </Menu>
</LanguageMenu>
```

With LINQ I would like to achieve to find all childrens beginning with Element MainItem that have value FIN3010.
Based on my XML it should return Vendors and Home Accounts.

I would also like to get the parents of that childer so the output I would like to achieve will be like this:

```
Traffic - Vendors
Traffic - Accounts - Home Accounts
```

I have stucked with this piece of code:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("../../xmlFile");
var x = from a in xelement.Descendants("SECONDS")
        where a.Attribute("value") != null 
        && (string)a.Attribute("value").Value.ToUpper() == txtSifra.Text.ToUpper()
        select a;
foreach (XElement xEle in x)
{
    //TODO
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
var x = from a in xelement.Descendants("MainItem")
                          .Descendants()
        where a.Attribute("value") != null && 
              a.Attribute("value").Value
                                  .Equals(txtSifra.Text, 
                                          StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        select a;
foreach (XElement xEle in x)
{
        // items will contain all nodes (inclusive) between MainItem and xEle
        var items = xEle.AncestorsAndSelf()
                        .Where(x1 => x1.AncestorsAndSelf("MainItem")
                                       .Any())
                        .OrderBy(x1 => x1.Ancestors().Count());
        var names = items.Attributes("name").Select(a => a.Value).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" - ", names));
}
```

The output from this is:

```
Traffic - Vendors
Traffic - Accounts - Home Accounts
```

Comment: Yes, it is working. Tell me please how can I get parents of every child.

Comment: No - it is not what I want. This piece of code return TAG of an founded item and then the whole 'MainItem' tag where this item is. I would like to achieve to give me output 'Traffic - Vendors' - name attribute of child and parents.

Comment: I figured you would be able to figure out the rest. See my modified answer above. Is that what you want, or do you want the values in a string? Or a list of strings? You haven't given very much information on that point.